# How to find all array elements that match both arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is there an easy way to iterate through 2 arrays and find any element values that are exactly the same in both arrays and populate it into a new array?

For example:

```
arr_a = ["a","b","c","d"]

arr_b = ["123","456","b","d","c"]
```

The array I want to create would be:

```
new_arr = ["b","c","d"]
```

I tried this:

```
another_arr = [*arr_a, *arr_b] #combines the 2 arrays
another_arr.select { |e| another_arr.count(e) >1 }.uniq #then find all dupes
```

but I don't know how to push the results to an array.

Is this the right way of going about it? Are there any ideas how push the results to an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is a Set Intersection, which can be achieved in Ruby using the `&` operator.

```
arr_a = ["a","b","c","d"]

arr_b = ["123","456","b","d","c"]

new_array = arr_a & arr_b
```

Read more about this in "[ary & other_ary](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26)".

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for intersection of two sets. This is way simpler:

```
arr_a & arr_b
```